# Pug file not rendering my iframe which is in a variable instead, rendering false

Tags: express, pug

On my controller i am sending a variable `embed` that contains an iframe, but it is rendering `false`, what i'm i doing wrong?

```
exports.getUserBySlug = async (req, res, next) => {

  const user = await User.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug })
  let embed = {}
  if (!user) return next();

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=json&url=${user.musicLink}`)
    embed = response.data
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }

  res.render('user', {
    user,
    title: user.name,
    embed: embed.html,
  });
};
```

Pug:

```
extends layout

block content
  .inner
    .cf
      .w-30.fl.ba
        img.br-100.h5.w5.center.db.mt4(src=`/uploads/${user.photo}`)
        p.tc #{user.name}
          p.tc #{user.genres}
      .w-70.fl.bg-light-blue
        user.musicLink
        p=! embed
```

Then on the rendered file it only renders false, how can i make the actual iframe to render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its typo mistake on your template, Where `p=! embed` should be `p!=embed`

> [Unescaped buffered code](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#unescaped-buffered-code) starts with !=. It evaluates the
>   JavaScript expression and outputs the result. Unescaped buffered code
>   does not perform any escaping, so is unsafe for user input